# Convert Object property value into float

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following data structure:

```
    const data = [
     {a: '12.03', b: '2.45', c: '24.12'},
     {a: '12.03', b: '22.45', c: '44.12'},
     {a: '15.03', b: '12.45', c: '24.12'},
     .
     .
     .
     n
    ]
```

And I want to convert the string into a float:

```
const data = [
     {a: 12.03, b: 2.45, c: 24.12},
     {a: 12.03, b: 22.45, c: 44.12},
     {a: 15.03, b: 12.45, c: 24.12}
    ]
```

Any Idea on how to iterate over the object and just apply the format so I can use the data array in a line chart?

Comment: Simplest is the unary `+` operator: `data.forEach(obj => Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>obj[key]=+obj[key]));
`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 data = data.map(({ a, b, c }) => ({ a: parseFloat(a), b: parseFloat(b), c: parseFloat(c) }));
```

or more general:

```
 data = data.map(entry => 
   Object.entries(entry).reduce(
       (obj, [key, value]) => (obj[key] = parseFloat(value), obj), 
       {}
   )
 );
```

Comment: Your making people horizontally scroll, just so that it's a one-liner.. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it working with the more general solution. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Everyone seems to want to use `parseFloat`, but I personally think it's just as readable, as well as much more concise/idiomatic, to use the unary `+`:

```
data.map(obj => ({a: +obj.a, b: +obj.b, c: +obj.c}));
```

I guess I'm in the minority, but I'll leave this here anyway in case this is useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use lodash [`mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapValues) for this.

```
const parsed = data.map(item => _.mapValues(item, parseFloat))
```

This simply takes each item, and iterates over the keys, changing the value using `parseFloat`. Compared to the `reduce` method, this is much more readable, and less prone to bugs as you aren't reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with some simple for loops.

```
const data = [
 {a: '12.03', b: '2.45', c: '24.12'},
 {a: '12.03', b: '22.45', c: '44.12'},
 {a: '15.03', b: '12.45', c: '24.12'},
];

//Loop through each array
for (var arr in data){
//Loop through eact data point
        for (var point in data[point]){
    //Convert to float
            data[point][i] = parseFloat(data[point][i])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript parseFloat() to convert a string into a float.

```
parseFloat('12.03')
```

returns

```
12.03
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over each of the data items and transform them into your desired format:

```
const result = data.map(value => ({ 
  a: parseFloat(value.a), 
  b: parseFloat(value.b), 
  c: parseFloat(value.c) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You run a function through every element of the array with `.map` (every object), then if you don't know the keys or the amount of keys, you can loop through each of the object's key with `Object.keys(el)`, and then using `parseFloat` to do the trick.

```
data.map((el) => {
  Object.keys(el).forEach((key) => {
      el[key] = parseFloat(el[key])
  })
})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Code only answers are discouraged and will be deleted eventually.